# How to make Cloudio work in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef, word-cloud, zest

I want to use word-clouds in my Eclipseplugin. I've come to the conclusion that using [Cloudio](https://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF/GEF4/Cloudio) would be the best solution. But I sadly can't make it work.

When I try to re-create one of the examples on the website, I get unresolved imports, for example:

```
The import org.eclipse.zest.cloudio cannot be resolved
```

But I can neither find Cloudio when I try to add id as a required plugin to the manifest, nor I can find a jar anywhere. So how to I make Cloudio work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured how it's done:

1. Download GEF4.Cloudio from Help -> Install new Software using site: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/gef4/updates/releases.
2. Now you can add GEF4.Cloudio in the manifest required plugin-ins.
3. When using examples from the Cloudio wiki page, replace org.eclipse.zest.cloudio... with org.eclipse.gef4.cloudio...